# mysql order by + limit slows query down

Tags: mysql

It seems using order by + limit is really slow, using order by is somewhat slow, and using just limit is pretty fast. The explains for these queries all use filesort. The like is wild-carded on both ends '%search%' so I know it can't use an index.

I don't understand why an order by with a limit is so much slower than just an order by.

If I have the follow query it takes about 250 ms: (There are multiple similar queries in the same format). This uses order by AND limit. (Slowest)

```
$this->db->select('category');
$this->db->from('items');
$this->db->where('deleted',0);
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->like('category', $search);
$this->db->order_by("category", "asc");
$this->db->limit($limit);
```

If I have the follow query it takes about 65ms ms (There are multiple similar queries in the same format). This uses just LIMIT (fastest)

```
$this->db->select('category');
$this->db->from('items');
$this->db->where('deleted',0);
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->like('category', $search);
$this->db->limit($limit);
```

If I have the follow query it takes about 75ms ms (There are multiple similar queries in the same format)

```
$this->db->select('category');
$this->db->from('items');
$this->db->where('deleted',0);
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->like('category', $search);
$this->db->order_by("category", "asc");
```

Comment: `Order by` requires sorting the entire result set.  This takes time.  `limit` just returns the rows as the SQL engine encounters them.

Comment: You could try adding index covering columns (deleted, category), or just index covering column category.

Comment: You might like to index the `category` column to improve queries which use `order by category`.

Comment: You omitted `$this->db->select('category');` in the last query. Did you test this query without `select`. What happening if you add `select` in the last query

Comment: @Gordon Linoff my main question is though why would a limit added to an order by query decrease performance a lot.

Comment: @ChrisMuench Would you emphasis your core question? The people here misunderstand the problem. Anyway, I tried this out on some of my tables and can't observe this behavior.

Comment: Write all these queries in text file (do not use framework) and test them and look EXPLAIN. Maybe MySQL changes strategy when you add `LIMIT` + `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('category');
$this->db->from('items');
$this->db->where('deleted',0);
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->like('category', $search);
$this->db->limit($limit);
```

This query works in this way:

1. MySQL scan table `items` using index or using sequence scan.
2. When category matches condition `category LIKE $search`, MySQL returns this record to You.
3. When $limit reached, MySQL stops execution. This going fast. (I assume that `$limit` was not so big in your tests)

But query with `ORDER BY` is executed in other way:

```
$this->db->select('category');
$this->db->from('items');
$this->db->where('deleted',0);
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->like('category', $search);
$this->db->order_by("category", "asc");
$this->db->limit($limit);
```

1. MySQL scan table `items` using index or using sequence search to the end of table.
2. When category matches condition `category LIKE $search`, MySQL store this record somewhere (temporary file or memory cache)
3. MySQL sorts all records in temporary file or memory cache
4. Using sequence scan it reads $limit records from cache and returns them to you.

In first query MySQL does minimum $limit comparisons. In second query MySQL does comparisons as much as records in table and then does sorting of (I assume) a big recordset.

**UPD** Sorry, It isn't answer to your question.

Write all these queries in text file (do not use framework) and test them and look EXPLAIN.
Maybe MySQL changes strategy when you add 'LIMIT'

Comment: His question was that why the query is slower with both limit AND order by than using only order by. Intuition tells that using a limit would speed up the query, as fewer i/o is required to return the rows.